# Multiple instances of a rigged object

Tags: rigging, linked-data, instances

Is there a way to have multiple rigged objects that share mesh data?

I have a big hall, and want to use a rigged lamp that I have on separate file, let's say "lamp.blend". The lamp and the armature are in a group.

As per another answer, I made several hard links to the original file (lamp-01.blend, lamp-02.blend ...), and linked (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) the group once per file.

Then I made the armature a proxy object, and parented the armature to the empty (otherwise moving the empty would not move the armature), once per group.

All was fine and dandy, until the next day, when I opened the file to a series of errors:

> LIB: Armature: 'Lamp.001_proxy' missing from '/home/.../lamp-01.blend', parent ''

one per proxy object. The menu option "find missing files" didn't help.

What happened? How am I supposed to do the linking?

Thanks to all,
Piergi

Comment: This (multiple linked instances with proxy rigs) is not supported yet, you need to have as much copies of the rigged group as the number of instances you wanna use.

Comment: @Jerryno : I made a copy of the library file for every instance (they are linked files, but it seems to work)